# Masking raster with another raster

Tags: r, raster, spatial

I have a raster image with both numerical values and also NA's and would like to use it as a mask to remove values in a different raster. Does the raster package allow for this?

Example:

Raster A originally had values ranging from 0-1. I applied a raster calculation so that if values are <0.6, then they are transformed to NA. The resulting raster is a mix of values from 0.6 to 1 and NA's. I want to use Raster A to "mask" values from Raster B (Raster B values range from 0 to 1 also) so that if the value in Raster A = NA, then the same cell in Raster B = NA and if the cell in Raster A has a value of 0.6 to 1, then keep the corresponding cell value in Raster B. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `overlay` with the two rasters. Here, I first create two sample rasters using the `volcano` dataset. Then, I randomly assign `NA`s to the first raster (`rst1`). Then, apply `overlay` to change the cells in `rst2` to `NA`s for those that match the `NA` cells in `rst1`.

```
library(raster)

rst <- raster::raster(volcano)
rst1 <- rst
rst2 <- rst

# Assign some random cells NAs in rst1.
set.seed(123)
id <- sample(1:ncell(rst), 1000)
rst1[id] <- NA

# Assign NA to the cells where NA is present in rast1.
rst2_mod <- overlay(
  rst2,
  rst1,
  fun = function(x, y) {
    x[is.na(y[])] <- NA
    return(x)
  }
)

plot(rst2_mod)
```

**Output**

[image]

Another option is to just use `calc` (using `rst1` and `rst2` from above). We can stack the two raster layers, then change the cell to `NA` if there are any `NA`s present for that cell.

```
s.new <-
  raster::calc(
    raster::stack(rst2, rst1),
    fun = function(x)
      if (sum(is.na(x)) > 0)
        x * NA
    else
      x
  )

plot(s.new)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mask` for masking:

Example data

```
library(terra)
B <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
set.seed(0)
A <- ifel(init(B, runif) > 0.6, NA, B)
```

Solution

```
x <- mask(B, A)
```